# AltBeacon library with Bluetooth 5 (beacon detectable range)

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

I'm using the Altbeacon library currently.
I used `ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY` and `ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH` for the transmitter app, and my device supports Bluetooth 5. So I guessed the beacon should be detectable in about 30~50m range. However, the beacon was detected in about 5~7 meters instead of the expected range.

All I want to ask is, As far as I know, Bluetooth 5.x is a standard that extends the communication range, so why are beacons still only detected within 6-7 meters? There is an any option for extend detectable range in `BeaconManager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points:

- Bluetooth 5 is largely a marketing term.  Just because a device says it supports Bluetooth 5 doesn't mean it supports all "optional" features.  I learned this the hard way when trying to program a Raspberry Pi 4 with BLE 5.  Long range advertising is an optional feature.
- When it comes to long range advertising, the specific feature you are talking about is called Coded PHY.  This is a physical layer that uses hamming codes for forward error correction.  This is what enables advertising to be detected at long range despite the same radio power.
- The Android Beacon Library's transmitter and scanner do not use long-range BLE 5 features even if the device hardware and bluetooth stack supports it.  The reason we have not put support into the library for this is because there remains very little opportunity to use this feature -- iPhones do not support it, very few hardware beacons support it, and even many newer Android devices do not support it.
- Android 8.0+ has APIs to enable this. You want to use PHY_LE_CODED for both advertising and scanning. To play with it, you'll need to phones that support PHY_LE_CODED. Read more here: https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising